# Restricting the x being counted in a historgram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

```
library(alr4)
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
ggplot(walleye, aes(x= age)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(~age)
```

I would like to create 4 histograms from the data set walleye. I would like the histograms to be for the length of the walleye. The for histograms should each have their own age for counting. I would like to restrict the ages from 1 to 4. How can I do that with ggplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, this should help:

```
library(alr4)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(subset(walleye, age<5), aes(x=length)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(~age)
```

This way you are only plotting the subset of the data where age is 1-4, and you are actually plotting histograms of length.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this too (adding another line of code on top of your code):

```
library(alr4)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(walleye, aes(x= age)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(~age)
p %+% subset(walleye, age %in% 1:4)
```

[image]